# change the size of a Div based on the screen size with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

What is wrong in my jquery? I would like to make my div bigger depending on screen size and there is plenty of good examples, but still no success.

```
  var screenWidth = screen.width;
  if (screenWidth < 1024) {

      $(".gadgetblockLeft1").css("width","40%");
  }  else {
        $(".gadgetblockLeft1").css("width","100%");
  }
```

and the css still :-

```
.gadget .gadgetblockLeft1 { padding:5px; background-color:#f4f4f4; border:1px solid #cfcfcf; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-align:right; direction:rtl; margin-left:5px; height:auto; float:left}
```

i need when change screen to 900px or less than 900px it will add this code `width:100%` to class `.gadgetblockLeft1`

Comment: Change `if (screenWidth < 1024)` to `if (screenWidth > 900)` ?

Comment: You should be using media queries for this, not JS. See @torazaburo's answer, and besides you seem to be unsure about what will happen with your code. The jQuery will not append your changes to the class itself, but to the element with the selector you have defined.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a media query:

```
.gadgetblockLeft1 { width: 40%; }
@media (min-width: 1024px) { .gadgetblockLeft1 { width: 100%; } }
```

This approach has the advantage that it will automatically do the right thing when the screen width changes, due to resizing the window for example.

Comment: How does it not work? Remember that the `width` property is interpreted relevant to the "layout parent" of the element, which may not be the body of the page, if there are intervening elements with the CSS `position` property set. We'd need to see more of your code to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {         
    if ($(window).width() <= 900) {
       $(".gadget .gadgetblockLeft1").css("width","100%");
    }
    });
```